# Calling Python code from R

Tags: r, python-3.x, rpython

I am trying to call my python code from R. This is a simple code i have tried.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a1=tf.constant(23)
b1=tf.constant(25)
s1=tf.Session()

with tf.Session() as s1:
    out=s1.run(a1+b1)
    print (out)
```

Using rPython (R-library) i tried for calling this function.

```
library(rPython)
# Load/run the main Python script
python.load("/Desktop/add.py")
```

But error occurred for this.

```
Error in python.exec(code, get.exception) : 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines(file) :
  incomplete final line found on '/Desktop/add.py'
```

But i have installed tensorflow in R as **install_tensorflow()** . 
I couldn't find the issue. Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The first warning message is indicating that your TensorFlow files were not added to the specified directories.

The final message indicates that the last line of `/Desktop/add.py` doesn't end with an **End Of Line (EOL) character** (linefeed (`\n`) or carriage return+linefeed (`\r\n`)). The original intention of this message was to warn you that the file may be incomplete; most datafiles have an EOL character as the very last character in the file.

To fix it:

1. Open `/Desktop/add.py` in your text editor
2. Navigate to the very last line of the file
3. Place the cursor the end of that line
4. Press `return`
5. Save the file